# Superbyke RSP 125 no electric not starting

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, starting

I have a 2015 Superbyke RSP 125 it fell off the stand and it was on its side two hrs tops. Was laying on its right hand side, no power at all but battery saying 12v on a meter but no dash lights, no life in it since. Tried battery fuses but nothing.

The side that the bike went down on has got a rectifier and I don't know if that would cause the lack of electric? Came back to bike and was on its side two hrs tops. Was laying on its right hand side, no power at all but battery saying 12v on a meter no dash lights.

Year of bike is 2015 hope you can help

Comment: How long was the bike left on it's side? Can you see any physical damage to any components?

Comment: Which side did it fall on?  What year is the bike?  Are you getting no power to come on at all?

Comment: Do you have a sealed battery or a vented battery?  Did you notice any battery acid that had leaked out when the bike was on its side?

Comment: So your bike is not starting ?

Answer (score 2):

**It might be your tipover sensor**

You have a tipover sensor on your bike behind the battery.  It's a little black box that has an arrow on it.  If it came loose when your bike fell over and the arrow is not pointed towards the sky you need to reseat it.

The tipover sensor stops the engine from running if the bike falls over in order to prevent engine damage due to lack of oil pressure.

Validate the tipover sensor arrow is pointed up and that the tipover sensor has not come loose from it's rubber mounting mechanism.